# Is the Android NotePad tutorial compatible with version 2 of Android?

Tags: android

Here's my story.

1. I downloaded the [NotePad tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp) project exercise files.
2. I created an Android project based on the tutorial files for the completed exercise (located in the Notepadv3Solution folder)
3. I run the project and bellow is a screenshot of what appears:

[image]

It doesn't seem to be working properly.

Could it be because I'm on version 2.2?

Comment: Apps are forward compatible with future Android versions, see here: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html#fc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's exactly what you should see. As I remember, you can add new notes by pressing the Menu button.